# Multiple file Upload - Multipart form data maximum limit

Tags: spring, file, rest, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload multiple files with the following request along with stringed JSON object:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params"

{"data":{"userName":"jim","description":"test","email":"jim@ox.com"}}
-----------------------------5366762814869373672043632099
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file0"

VBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFwAAAA/CAYAAABtj6+sAAAYJ2lDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAWIWVeQdUFE2zds
 ..... (content of file0)
-----------------------------5366762814869373672043632099
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"

cBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEsAAABpCAYAAAByKt7XAAAYJ2lDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAWIWVeQdUFE2zds 
..... (content of file1)
  -----------------------------5366762814869373672043632099--
```

file0 is of 16KB and file1 is of 12KB

and My spring controller method looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/addFile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void addFilesWithParams(MultipartFormDataInput filesData)
{
//some logic
}
```

But always ends up with one file saved and second file is ignored.
So i went ahead debuged my code and found out that On REST side I am only getting 2 Parts of the form i.e params and file0 and file1 is totaly ignored.[image]

As you can see in the above snap it says size is 2, even if  3 or 4 parts are being sent from ui.

So my guess is there is some Size cap that I have to override or specify.

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: Would like to add that I am using Tomcat 7 between UI and REST, if that helps in any way.

Comment: Just checked it again, I got a warning too 
saying:
2016-04-28 14:38:00,669 WARN [org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeEntity] - Body part ended prematurely. Boundary detected in header or EOF reached.